# Как передать объект, чтобы открыть его на новой странице?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, spa

Добры вечер, суть вопроса: у меня есть массив с объектами, у каждого объекта есть параметры, такие как name, id ,discription, date и т.д. Я создал таблицу, где вывел несколько параметров и каждое имя сделал ссылкой, чтобы открывать новую страницу по имени и выводить остальные параметры. Но столкнулся проблемой:

1. Как передать значение объекта, который я хочу открыть на новой странице? Я думал через хеш, но не выходит.
2. Не создавать же, если у меня 50 объектов, 50 страниц и 50 других контроллеров. Может, кто напишет, что прочесть, что где глянуть?

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", [ 'ngRoute']);

 myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when('/:tasks.name',{
            templateURL:'pages.html',
            controller:"mainController"
            })


 });

myApp.controller("mainController", function($scope, $http){


$scope.tasks= [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Today_task1",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
    "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
    "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 5.5,
    "actual_effort": 3.3,
    "physical_progress": 60,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
    "project_id": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Today_task11",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
    "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
    "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 5.5,
    "actual_effort": 3.3,
    "physical_progress": 60,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
    "project_id": 0,
    "tags": [
      "meeting"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Today_task12",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
    "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
    "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 5.5,
    "actual_effort": 3.3,
    "physical_progress": 60,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
    "project_id": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "name": "Today_task13",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
    "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
    "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 5.5,
    "actual_effort": 3.3,
    "physical_progress": 60,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
    "project_id": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "Today_task14",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
    "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
    "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 5.5,
    "actual_effort": 3.3,
    "physical_progress": 60,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
    "project_id": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Today_task15",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
    "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
    "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 5.5,
    "actual_effort": 3.3,
    "physical_progress": 60,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
    "project_id": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "name": "Today_task16",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
    "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
    "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 5.5,
    "actual_effort": 3.3,
    "physical_progress": 60,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
    "project_id": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "name": "Today_task17",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
    "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
    "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 5.5,
    "actual_effort": 3.3,
    "physical_progress": 60,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
    "project_id": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "name": "Today_task18",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
    "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
    "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 5.5,
    "actual_effort": 3.3,
    "physical_progress": 60,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
    "project_id": 0,
    "tags": [
      "Cerri",
      "task"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "name": "Today_task19",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
    "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
    "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "is_high_priority": true,
    "estimated_effort": 5.5,
    "actual_effort": 3.3,
    "physical_progress": 60,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
    "project_id": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 20,
    "name": "Today_task21",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
    "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
    "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 5.5,
    "actual_effort": 3.3,
    "physical_progress": 60,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
    "project_id": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Today_task2",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-22T06:50:22",
    "due_date": "2015-04-22T00:00:00Z",
    "start_date": "2015-04-22T00:00:00Z",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 1.0,
    "actual_effort": 0.0,
    "physical_progress": 10,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "project_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Upcoming_task",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-22T06:50:23",
    "due_date": "2015-04-29T06:50:29",
    "start_date": "2015-04-28T00:00:00",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 5.0,
    "actual_effort": 0.0,
    "physical_progress": 100,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "project_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Old_task",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-22T06:50:24",
    "due_date": "2015-04-22T06:50:30",
    "start_date": "2015-04-18T00:00:00",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 5.0,
    "actual_effort": 0.0,
    "physical_progress": 50,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "project_id": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Future_task",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-22T06:50:25",
    "due_date": "2025-05-22T06:50:31",
    "start_date": "2025-05-18T00:00:00",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 5.0,
    "actual_effort": 0.0,
    "physical_progress": 0,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "project_id": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Archived_task",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-20T06:50:26",
    "due_date": "2015-04-22T06:52:32",
    "start_date": "2015-04-22T00:00:00",
    "is_completed": true,
    "is_archived": true,
    "estimated_effort": 5.0,
    "actual_effort": 5.0,
    "physical_progress": 50,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "project_id": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Trashed_task",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-19T06:50:27",
    "due_date": "2015-04-22T06:52:33",
    "start_date": "2015-04-22T00:00:00",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 23.0,
    "actual_effort": 15.0,
    "physical_progress": 50,
    "obj_status": "trashed",
    "project_id": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Deleted_task",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-18T06:50:28",
    "due_date": "2015-04-22T06:52:34",
    "start_date": "2015-04-22T00:00:00",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 10.0,
    "actual_effort": 1.0,
    "physical_progress": 50,
    "obj_status": "deleted",
    "project_id": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "name": "Completed_task",
    "creation_date": "2015-05-22T00:00:00",
    "due_date": "2015-05-26T00:00:00",
    "start_date": "2015-05-25T00:00:00",
    "is_completed": true,
    "is_archived": true,
    "estimated_effort": 5.0,
    "actual_effort": 4.0,
    "physical_progress": 100,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "project_id": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "name": "Future_task2",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-22T06:50:25",
    "due_date": "2025-05-22T06:50:31",
    "start_date": "2025-05-18T00:00:00",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 5.0,
    "actual_effort": 0.0,
    "physical_progress": 0,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "project_id": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "name": "Future_milestone",
    "creation_date": "2015-04-22T06:50:25",
    "due_date": "2025-07-10T00:00:00",
    "start_date": "2025-07-10T00:00:00",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "estimated_effort": 0.0,
    "actual_effort": 0.0,
    "physical_progress": 0,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "project_id": 4,
    "task_type": "milestone"
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "name": "Task_without_dates",
    "creation_date": "2015-06-26T06:50:21",
    "is_completed": false,
    "is_archived": false,
    "obj_status": "active",
    "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
    "project_id": 0
  }
];






});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>

</head>
<style type="text/css">
    td{
        vertical-align: middle !important;
    }
    .bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<body >
    <div class="container" ng-controller="mainController">
        <div class="row">

  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Название</th>
        <th>Статус</th>
        <th>Теги</th>
        <th>Время потраченное на задачу</th>
        <th>Оценкa</th>
        <th>Дата окончания задачи</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
       <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-if="task.obj_status =='active'" >
        <td ng-class="{'bold':task.is_high_priority == true}"><a href="{{task.name}}/pages.html">{{task.name}}</a></td>
        <td>{{task.obj_status}}</a></td>
        <td ><div ng-repeat = "tag in task.tags">{{tag}}</div></td>
        <td>{{task.actual_effort}}</td>
        <td>{{task.estimated_effort}}</td>
        <td >{{task.due_date|date :  "dd.MM.y h:mm:ss"}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Хранить объекты в сервисе
2. В url передавать id объекта
3. Контроллер достаёт объект по id из сервиса

```js
angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute'])

.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: "/pages.html",
      controller: "MainController"
    })
    .when('/task/:id', {
      templateUrl: "/task.html",
      controller: "TaskController"
    })
    .otherwise({
      template: '<h1>404</h1>'
    })
})

.factory("TasksService", function ($q) {
  var tasks = [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Today_task1",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
      "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
      "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 5.5,
      "actual_effort": 3.3,
      "physical_progress": 60,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
      "project_id": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "Today_task11",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
      "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
      "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 5.5,
      "actual_effort": 3.3,
      "physical_progress": 60,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
      "project_id": 0,
      "tags": [
        "meeting"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "Today_task12",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
      "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
      "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 5.5,
      "actual_effort": 3.3,
      "physical_progress": 60,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
      "project_id": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "name": "Today_task13",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
      "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
      "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 5.5,
      "actual_effort": 3.3,
      "physical_progress": 60,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
      "project_id": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "Today_task14",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
      "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
      "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 5.5,
      "actual_effort": 3.3,
      "physical_progress": 60,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
      "project_id": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 15,
      "name": "Today_task15",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
      "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
      "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 5.5,
      "actual_effort": 3.3,
      "physical_progress": 60,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
      "project_id": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "name": "Today_task16",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
      "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
      "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 5.5,
      "actual_effort": 3.3,
      "physical_progress": 60,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
      "project_id": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 17,
      "name": "Today_task17",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
      "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
      "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 5.5,
      "actual_effort": 3.3,
      "physical_progress": 60,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
      "project_id": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 18,
      "name": "Today_task18",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
      "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
      "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 5.5,
      "actual_effort": 3.3,
      "physical_progress": 60,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
      "project_id": 0,
      "tags": [
        "Cerri",
        "task"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 19,
      "name": "Today_task19",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
      "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
      "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "is_high_priority": true,
      "estimated_effort": 5.5,
      "actual_effort": 3.3,
      "physical_progress": 60,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
      "project_id": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 20,
      "name": "Today_task21",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-21T06:50:21",
      "due_date": "2015-04-22T23:59:00",
      "start_date": "2015-04-21T00:00:01",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 5.5,
      "actual_effort": 3.3,
      "physical_progress": 60,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
      "project_id": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Today_task2",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-22T06:50:22",
      "due_date": "2015-04-22T00:00:00Z",
      "start_date": "2015-04-22T00:00:00Z",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 1.0,
      "actual_effort": 0.0,
      "physical_progress": 10,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "project_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Upcoming_task",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-22T06:50:23",
      "due_date": "2015-04-29T06:50:29",
      "start_date": "2015-04-28T00:00:00",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 5.0,
      "actual_effort": 0.0,
      "physical_progress": 100,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "project_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Old_task",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-22T06:50:24",
      "due_date": "2015-04-22T06:50:30",
      "start_date": "2015-04-18T00:00:00",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 5.0,
      "actual_effort": 0.0,
      "physical_progress": 50,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "project_id": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Future_task",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-22T06:50:25",
      "due_date": "2025-05-22T06:50:31",
      "start_date": "2025-05-18T00:00:00",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 5.0,
      "actual_effort": 0.0,
      "physical_progress": 0,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "project_id": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Archived_task",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-20T06:50:26",
      "due_date": "2015-04-22T06:52:32",
      "start_date": "2015-04-22T00:00:00",
      "is_completed": true,
      "is_archived": true,
      "estimated_effort": 5.0,
      "actual_effort": 5.0,
      "physical_progress": 50,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "project_id": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Trashed_task",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-19T06:50:27",
      "due_date": "2015-04-22T06:52:33",
      "start_date": "2015-04-22T00:00:00",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 23.0,
      "actual_effort": 15.0,
      "physical_progress": 50,
      "obj_status": "trashed",
      "project_id": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Deleted_task",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-18T06:50:28",
      "due_date": "2015-04-22T06:52:34",
      "start_date": "2015-04-22T00:00:00",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 10.0,
      "actual_effort": 1.0,
      "physical_progress": 50,
      "obj_status": "deleted",
      "project_id": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 21,
      "name": "Completed_task",
      "creation_date": "2015-05-22T00:00:00",
      "due_date": "2015-05-26T00:00:00",
      "start_date": "2015-05-25T00:00:00",
      "is_completed": true,
      "is_archived": true,
      "estimated_effort": 5.0,
      "actual_effort": 4.0,
      "physical_progress": 100,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "project_id": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 22,
      "name": "Future_task2",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-22T06:50:25",
      "due_date": "2025-05-22T06:50:31",
      "start_date": "2025-05-18T00:00:00",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 5.0,
      "actual_effort": 0.0,
      "physical_progress": 0,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "project_id": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 23,
      "name": "Future_milestone",
      "creation_date": "2015-04-22T06:50:25",
      "due_date": "2025-07-10T00:00:00",
      "start_date": "2025-07-10T00:00:00",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "estimated_effort": 0.0,
      "actual_effort": 0.0,
      "physical_progress": 0,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "project_id": 4,
      "task_type": "milestone"
    },
    {
      "id": 24,
      "name": "Task_without_dates",
      "creation_date": "2015-06-26T06:50:21",
      "is_completed": false,
      "is_archived": false,
      "obj_status": "active",
      "description": "Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur_adipiscing_elit",
      "project_id": 0
    }
  ];
  
  return {
    getAll() {
      return $q.resolve(tasks);
    },
    getById(id) {
      return $q.resolve(tasks.find(t => t.id == id));
    },
  }
})

.controller("MainController", function($scope, TasksService) {
  TasksService.getAll().then(tasks => $scope.tasks = tasks);
})

.controller("TaskController", function($scope, $routeParams, TasksService) {
  TasksService.getById($routeParams.id).then(task => $scope.task = task);
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style type="text/css">td { vertical-align: middle !important; } .bold { font-weight: bold; } </style>

<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-view class="row"></div>
  
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/pages.html">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Название</th>
          <th>Статус</th>
          <th>Теги</th>
          <th>Время потраченное на задачу</th>
          <th>Оценкa</th>
          <th>Дата окончания задачи</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-if="task.obj_status =='active'">
          <td ng-class="{'bold':task.is_high_priority == true}"><a href="#!/task/{{task.id}}">{{task.name}}</a></td>
          <td>{{task.obj_status}}</td>
          <td>
            <div ng-repeat="tag in task.tags">{{tag}}</div>
          </td>
          <td>{{task.actual_effort}}</td>
          <td>{{task.estimated_effort}}</td>
          <td>{{task.due_date|date : "dd.MM.y h:mm:ss"}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </script>
  
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/task.html">
    <a href='#!/'>&lt; List</a>
    <pre>{{task | json}}</pre>
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно подробней?

Comment: @Boogie, сделал. А вопрос - просто издевательство - в нём всё что только можно сделано так, чтобы ничего не работало. В следующий раз без работающего сниппета в вопросе отвечать не стану.